# Element-wise operations in mpmath

Tags: python, mpmath

I am looking to perform element-wise [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/build/index.html) operations on Python arrays.  For example,

```
import mpmath as mpm
x = mpm.arange(0,4)
y = mpm.sin(x)        # error
```

Alternatively, using [`mpmath` matrices](http://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/build/matrices.html)

```
x = mpm.matrix([0,1,2,3])
y = mpm.sin(x)             # error
```

Does `mpmath` have any capibilities in this area, or is it necessary to loop through the entries?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

mpmath does not appear to handle element-wise operation, but you can use numpy to get this functionality:

```
import numpy as np
import mpmath as mpm
x = np.array(mpm.arange(0,4))

sin = np.vectorize(mpm.sin)
y = sin(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

`mpmath.arange` apparently returns regular Python lists, so you can use `map` to apply a function on each element:

```
import mpmath
x = mpmath.arange(0,4)
y = map(mpmath.sin, x)
```

Comment: Thanks nooodl, also a great idea.

Answer (score -1):

The apply method simply should work

```
A = mpmath.arange(0,4)

A.apply(sin)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'`

Comment: This actually works on matrices (though not on lists) which was the original question! Try
`x = mpm.matrix([0,1,2,3])`
`y = x.apply(mpm.sin)`